# Laravel 9: Llave foránea no primaria devuelve error 1822

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-9

Buen día,

Tengo dos tablas en un sitio web de la siguiente forma:

```
Schema::create('tabla_uno', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('year');
            $table->string('brand');
            $table->string('sub_brand');
            $table->string('version');
            $table->foreignId('id_a')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```
Schema::create('tabla_a', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('year');
            $table->string('brand');
            $table->string('brand_code');
            $table->string('sub_brand');
            $table->string('version');
            $table->string('code');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Donde la "tabla_uno" tiene una llave foranea "id_a" relacionada con el `id` de la "tabla_a".

Deseo agregar una nueva llave foránea a "tabla_uno" para relacionar la columna "code" de la "tabla_a", para eso cree una nueva migración para expandir la "tabla_uno" (Es decir, arriba tiene `return new class extends Migration`):

```
Schema::table('tabla_uno', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('code_a');
            $table->foreign('code_a')->references('code')->on('tabla_a')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Pero al intentar hacer la migración con `php artisan migrate` me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1822 Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'tabla_uno_code_a_foreign' in the referenced table 'tabla_a' (SQL: alter table `tabla_uno` add constraint `tabla_uno_code_a_foreign` foreign key (`code_a`) references `tabla_a` (`code`))
```

¿Cómo puedo crear esa llave foranea?

Comment: Creería que lo que te dice, es que la columna code en la tabla_a debería estar indexada. Prueba con algo así antes de agregar la fk `Schema::table('table_a', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('code')->index()->change();
});`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ, al intentarlo primero me apareció esto, yo creo por lo del update y delete cascade: ```SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`table`.`#sql-1b48_27e`, CONSTRAINT `table_one_code_a_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`code_a`) REFERENCES `table_a` (`code`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: alter table `table_one` add constraint `table_one_code_a_foreign` foreign key (`code_a`) references `table_a` (`code`) on delete cascade on update cascade)```

Comment: Y luego esto al intentar borrar los cascade y migrar nuevamente: ```SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1061 Duplicate key name 'table_a_code_index' (SQL: alter table `table_a` add index `table_a_code_index`(`code`))``` yo creo que de alguna forma se ejecutó parte de la migración y ahora "code" es `index`

Comment: Esto sucede porque cuando ejecutas las migraciones, la nueva columna: "code_a" todavía no está creada por lo tanto cuando va a relacionarla con "code" te indica que no existe. Te adjunto unos links que podrán ser útiles. [Error 1822: Failed to Add foreign key constraint Missing index for constraint](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291998/error-1822-failed-to-add-foreign-key-constraint-missing-index-for-constraint) [Crear y asociar tablas usando las migraciones de Laravel (con claves foráneas)](https://styde.net/crear-y-asociar-tablas-usando-las-migraciones-de-laravel-con-claves-foraneas

Comment: La página ya existe y las tablas existen así que la columna ya existe.

Comment: No he usado ChatGPT xD

Comment: Ya vi que al utilizar `index()->change() ahora convirtió esa columna en el índice único y principal, pero eso no es lo que deseo.

Comment: Por todo lo indagado, el Error 1822 indica lo que te he comentado. Yo lo revisaría por si acaso. Saludos

Comment: Si, fue lo primero que revisé, pero como las tablas ya existen, estoy viendo que tienen datos en esa columna y todo

Comment: Gracias @porloscerrosΨ, ya funciona, si era lo de los índices pero en lugar de cambiarlo, únicamente agregué la columna como un índice secundario. He redactado una respuesta y la he ocultado por el momento por si quieres agregar la tuya para aceptarla. Saludos!

Comment: Agrega la respuesta nomás, yo solo estaba comentando desde el movil

Comment: Añadan la respuesta, me puse a escribir sin ver los comentarios! :P

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/381531)

Comment: @Alfabravo, perdona, voy despertando, ya la recuperé. Si hay algo más que agregar o explicar puedes agregar la tuya también.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Las llaves foráneas deben ser índices, si no son índices va a aparecer el error 1822.

Gracias al comentario de `@porloscerrosΨ` convertí la columna a índice, pero sin cambiar el índice original ya que esta columna puede tener valores repetidos así que se agregó como índice secundario.

La nueva migración quedó así:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('table_a', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // Convertir la columna a índice
        $table->index('code');
    });

    Schema::table('table_one', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('code_a');
        $table->foreign('code_a')->references('code')->on('table_a');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('table_one', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign(['code_a']);
        $table->dropColumn('code_a');
    });

    Schema::table('table_a', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropIndex(['code']);
    });
}
```